# jQuery - Regex to prevent any special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery's validation plugin to validate a form.
I have a field which should only contain letters or numbers. I have tried the following regex but it's still allowing characters such as ' ; :

```
[a-zA-Z 0-9]$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any length requirements?

Comment: nope just that there are no special characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z 0-9]*$
```

If this is a required field, then change asterisk to plus:-

```
^[a-zA-Z 0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression::

```
^[a-zA-Z 0-9]+$
```